Changing font in Sankey diagram and saving the plot in PDF format
I am working with the package 'sfo' to prepare a Sankey diagram. Below, you can see both my code and my data
library(sfo)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(plotly)


sfo_passengers %>% 
  filter(operating_airline == "United Airlines",
         activity_period >= 201901 & activity_period < 202001) %>%
  mutate(terminal = ifelse(terminal == "International", "international", terminal)) %>%
  group_by(operating_airline,activity_type_code, geo_summary, geo_region,  terminal) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(passenger_count), .groups = "drop") %>%
  sankey_ly(cat_cols = c("operating_airline", "terminal","geo_summary", "geo_region", "activity_type_code"), 
            num_col = "total",
            title = "Dist. of United Airlines Passengers at SFO During 2019")

p <- plotly::last_plot()

plotly::add_annotations(p, c("Terminals", "Domestic/Int"), x = c(0.2, 0.5), y = c(1, 1), showarrow = FALSE)


Now I want to change two things in this diagram. First is to change the font and to use Arial font in bold, and second is to export this chart in PDF. Can anybody help with how to do this?

Using plotly::layout, you can modify various attributes of the plot, such as the font family.  To save the plot in PDF format, one can use the webshot package.
library(sfo)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

p <- sfo_passengers %>% 
  filter(operating_airline == "United Airlines",
         activity_period >= 201901 & activity_period < 202001) %>%
  mutate(terminal = ifelse(terminal == "International", "international", terminal)) %>%
  group_by(operating_airline,activity_type_code, geo_summary, geo_region,  terminal) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(passenger_count), .groups = "drop") %>%
  sankey_ly(cat_cols = c("operating_airline", "terminal","geo_summary", "geo_region", "activity_type_code"), 
            num_col = "total",
            title = "Dist. of United Airlines Passengers at SFO During 2019") %>%
  add_annotations(c("Terminals", "Domestic/Int"), x = c(0.2, 0.5), y = c(1, 1), showarrow = FALSE) %>%
  layout(font=list(family="Arial", size=30, color="red"), margin=list(t=100))

# Save the plotly plot to an HTML file
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(p, file="sankey_plot.html", selfcontained=TRUE)

# Take a screenshot of the plot saved in the html file
library(webshot)
webshot::install_phantomjs()
webshot("sankey_plot.html", "sankey_plot.pdf", vwidth = 1984, vheight = 1088, zoom=0.6)

The parameters vwidth, vheight, and zoom need to be finely tuned according to the specific characteristics of the chart.


In the PDF, chart is divided into two pages instead one. How I can extract in one PDF with dimension 8.27x11.69 inches with landscape orientation ?

@silent_hunter Try to reduce the value of the zoom parameter. You can also fine-tune the vwidth and vheight parameters.
